# error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tree : MonoBehaviour {

public int Health = 5;
public Transform logs;
public Transform coconut;
public GameObject tree;

public Camera myCamera;

public int speed = 8;

void Start () {
    tree = this.gameObject;
    GetComponent <Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    myCamera = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Health > 0)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, myCamera.transform.root.transform.position) < 10f)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && WeaponSwitching.check == true)
            {
                Ray ray = new Ray(myCamera.transform.position,myCamera.transform.forward);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,10f))
                {
                    if(hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
                    {
                        --Health;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

     if(Health <= 0)
    {
        GetComponent <Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        GetComponent <Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
        DestroyTree();
    }
}

void DestroyTree()
{

    wait ();

Destroy(tree);

Vector3 position = Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0), 0, Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0));
Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + Vector3(0,0,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + Vector3(2,2,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + Vector3(5,5,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);

Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + Vector3(0,0,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + Vector3(2,2,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + Vector3(5,5,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
}

IEnumerator wait()
{
    yield return  new WaitForSeconds (7.0f);
}
}
```

it is showing that object cannot be converted to UnityEngine.Vector3. how can i convert object to Vector3 type. the error is shown in the ***INSTANTIATE*** function. it is saying tree.transform.position + Vector3(0,0,0) + position is an object type. how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you have **1** compile time error in your code, you stop and fix it before writing more code. You can't just create errors on top of other errors in your code.

There are more than **13** errors in your code but only **2** mistakes created those errors.

**1**.You must use a `new` keyword to create a **new** vector. One exception is when you are calling `static` functions or constructors such as `Vector3.zero`,`Vector3.up` and so on.

So replace `Vector3(Random.Range...` with `new Vector3(Random.Range.....`

**And** `tree.transform.position + Vector3(0, 0, 0)` with `tree.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0)`

Do this for 5 other mistakes too.

**2**.`Vector3` takes `float`,`float`,`float` as a parameter not `int`,`int`,`int`.

In this line of `Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0), 0, Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0))`;, you are passing in `int` to `Vector3` instead of `float`. To fix this, you put **f** after each value in the `Random.Range` function. The **f** lets the compiler know that this is a `float` not `int`. If you don't. Random.Range int overload method will be called instead of float function overload.

So again change `Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0), 0, Random.Range(-1.0, 1.0));` to `new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f));`.

```
public class Tree : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int Health = 5;
    public Transform logs;
    public Transform coconut;
    public GameObject tree;

    public Camera myCamera;

    public int speed = 8;

    void Start()
    {
        tree = this.gameObject;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        myCamera = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Health > 0)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, myCamera.transform.root.transform.position) < 10f)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && WeaponSwitching.check == true)
                {
                    Ray ray = new Ray(myCamera.transform.position, myCamera.transform.forward);
                    RaycastHit hit;
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10f))
                    {
                        if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
                        {
                            --Health;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
            DestroyTree();
        }
    }

    void DestroyTree()
    {

        wait();

        Destroy(tree);

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f));
        Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(2, 2, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(logs, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(5, 5, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);

        Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(2, 2, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + new Vector3(5, 5, 0) + position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    IEnumerator wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow shame on me for not seeing all that, i admit i was only looking for the error in the title. minor mixup, 1.0 would be the notation of a double, not integer (only for completeness, im sure *you* know it)

Comment: @yes yeah I put int because the Random function think that's an int and therefore uses the int return overload. There should be no shame because it's hard to find that just by looking at it. I had to create the file to find that out.

Answer (score 2):

its a simple typo when you instanciate coconuts.

`Instantiate(coconut, tree,transform.position + Vector3(0,0,0) + position, Quaternion.identity);`

should be

`Instantiate(coconut, tree.transform.position + position, Quaternion.identity);`

also dont GetComponent repeatedly, cache a reference. But I only skimmed over the code.

edit:
Oh and while i just read this, adding Vector3(0,0,0) to something is pretty nonsensical, - its like adding 0 to something, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: what changes have you made then?

Comment: compair the two lines. you may want to learn spotting such typos on first sight when planning to programm. such things are as common as missing semicolons ...

Comment: Just in case you're struggling, it's the comma just after `tree`. Sorry for ruining the game of spot the difference!

Comment: also include the previous and next line, it sometimes is "off" by one :D